# Changing navigation using Susy

Tags: layout, grid, breakpoints, susy-compass

How can I change the layout of different elements of a page using Susy, for instance, change the top navigation of a page from a bar when on desktop, but a button with a dropdown when on mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `at-breakpoint` mixin ([see the docs](http://susy.oddbird.net/guides/reference/#ref-responsive)):

```
// mobile styles here

@include at-breakpoint($min-screen-width $large-columns) {
  // screen styles here
}
```

You can also see at-breakpoint in several demos on the Susy site.